# How can I request the password to be numbers only to create new users?

Tags: php, html, authentication, passwords, number-formatting

How can I request the password to be numbers only to create new users?

It might a silly question, but I didn't find how to let the password to be numbers only [0-9]!
Another related question: How could I request the password to be numbers [1-9] only?

I tried this but it didn't work!

```
<input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" type="number" value="<?php echo htmlentities($password); ?>" />
```

Comment: Type=number is only works in new generation browser

Comment: Why should the password be only numbers? What's wrong with just letting them type anything?

Comment: @Jack: I have an idea that I want to proof it :)

Comment: Passwords should not be restricted in any way without very good reasons, except a minimum length. So i would be interested in your idea too.

Comment: You all are correct, let me show you the idea once I finish it, apologize me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the server-side checks (a must) and client-side JavaScript checks (good for usability), you can use the HTML5 `pattern` attribute. It is supported by some browsers, and in them, it provides the client-side check even when JavaScript is disabled. Example:

```
<input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" pattern="\d+">
```

The [MDN info on `input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) is outdated in this respect. According to HTML5 CR, the `pattern` attribute is allowed for [`input type=password][2]`, too, and modern browsers (including IE 10) support it that way.

Comment: Thankful.. it was great enough, but what about numbers from [1-9] only?

Comment: I did search in developer.mozilla.org, but I didn't find anything about pattern="\d+" ..!? how can I find more information about it?

Comment: To allow digits from 1 to 9 only, use `pattern="[1-9]+"`. The syntax of the value is the same as in JavaScript regular expressions, except that a match for the entire string is required; this roughly speaking corresponds to implied `^` at the start and implied `$` at the end of the pattern.

Comment: I didn't understand the rest of your comment, but `pattern="[1-9]+"` is quite enough for me at the meantime.. it worked well :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expression like this

```
$pass = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $password );
```

this will only take the numeric value between 0 to 9. For 1 to 9 just change the value.
Also theres a [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) or [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function for php

```
if(is_numeric($pass)){
$password = $pass;
} else {
//Error message
}
```

Comment: I'm interesting in this one, I'll try it, but I'll better use is_int, correct?

Comment: regular expression could be an alternative but it is your choice. Choose in where you feel comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 `type` attributes in your code, I think that will not work. Let the `type` be `password`.

Validate the user input in javascript or php and if the input is number, only then save to darabase.

In javascript use function `isNaN`

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

In php use `is_numeric`

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: You shouldn't link documentation to w3schools. Details can be found [here](http://w3fools.com). You may want to link to [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) instead.

Comment: Data should be validated client-side *and* server-side, and the latter is usually more important. Client-side checks are far too easy to bypass.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript to capture key presses (`keyup`) and throw away the ones that aren't numbers. Basically, you take the value entered into the `input`, remove the last character, and then put it back. With jQuery this is actually super easy.

You can use a server-side check and then inform your user that they need to start over... but if that's ever happened to you, you'll know what a crappy UI that makes for. JavaScipt is client-side for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

It should be server side check, because otherwise can be easily manipulated by the front-end.

You can use regular expressions to manipulate the input or simply check it by:

```
if (is_int($_POST['password'])) {
  // continue
}
else {
  // break
}
```

`is_int` docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php there are also related functions

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkNumKey(evt)
  {
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
     if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

     return true;
  }
```

Include this function in the script tag. 
And call it on textBox however you want

e.g.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="javascript:return checkNumKey(event);" />
```

Comment: that would not prevent pasting text into the field, doesn't it? I would recommend to check the entire field against a regex after any keypress `.replace(/[^0-9]/, '')`

Comment: If you do this...you should ALSO use server-side checking...but this will help provide feedback to users who do have JS enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If u are looking for a client side validation you can use jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name_ajax").change(function(){

        if($.isNumeric($("#name_ajax").val())){
        return;
        }
        else {
        alert ('not allowed');
        }
    }
})
```

where `name_ajax` is the id of the text field.

Don't forget to include the jquery library